# How do you prove that $\arcsin( \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2-\sqrt {2-2x}})=\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{1}{4} \arcsin x$?

Tags: trigonometry

I have the task to prove that

$$
     \arcsin( \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2-\sqrt {2-2x}})=\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{1}{4} \arcsin x ,\left|x\right|\le 1
$$

[image]

I do not have any ideas from where I should start.

Can anyone help me solve it?

Comment: There is a typo in your question. It's rather $\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{1}{4} \arcsin (x/2)$ on the right hand side. **See my answer below**.

Comment: @Olivier Where is the typo?

Comment: The argument is $x/2$ on the right hand side...

Comment: As it stands the identity is **not correct.**

Comment: @Olivier I cannot answer this question fully as I am confused by the brackets under the square root

Answer (score 4):

Let $\arcsin( \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2-\sqrt {2-x}})=y$

$\implies-\dfrac\pi2\le y\le\dfrac\pi2$

and $\dfrac12\sqrt{2-\sqrt {2-x}}=\sin y$

$\implies2-\sqrt {2-x}=(2\sin y)^2$

Using $\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1=1-2\sin^2A,$

$\sqrt {2-x}=2-4\sin^2y=2\cos2y$

$\implies x=2-(2\cos2y)^2=-2\cos4y$

$\implies\cos4y=-\dfrac x2$

$\arccos\left(-\dfrac x2\right)=\begin{cases}2\pi+4y  &\mbox{if }  -2\pi\le4y<-\pi \\-4y &\mbox{if }  -\pi\le4y<0\\ 4y &\mbox{if } 0\le4y\le\pi \\
2\pi-4y & \mbox{if }\pi<4y\le2\pi \end{cases}$

Now $\arccos\left(-\dfrac x2\right)=\dfrac\pi2-\arcsin\left(-\dfrac x2\right)$

$\implies\arccos\left(-\dfrac x2\right)=\dfrac\pi2+\arcsin\dfrac x2$   as $\arcsin(-u)=-\arcsin u$

Answer (score 2):

You may just observe that, for $x \in [0,1)$, we have
$$
\left(\arcsin\left( \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2-\sqrt {2-2x}}\right)\right)'=\frac14\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$ and we have
$$
\left(\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{1}{4} \arcsin x\right)'=\frac14\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$ giving

> $$
> \arcsin( \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{2-\sqrt {2-2x}})=\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{1}{4} \arcsin x, \quad x \in [0,1]
> $$

since **both functions take the same value at** $x=0$ and at $x=1$.